# "defaultValue" in react-select does not select option in dropdown but "value" select the option in dropdown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm learning react and have come across `react-select` behaviour which i'm unable to understand.

I've a `react-select` component whose values are being fetched from an api call. If I use `defaultValue` then it doesn't select that value from dropdown but if i use `value` then it selects value for the dropdown.

I'm just confused why `defaultValue` is not working.

```
<Select
  key={`dropdown`}
  options={options}
  onChange={onSelect}
  defaultValue={defaultValue} />
```

where 'options' are being passed as props from other component where they are being fetched from an api call.

`defaultValue` is also being passed as prop and have structure like this:

```
defaultValue = {
  label: `Test label`,
  value: `Test value`
}
```

But now if I change the select component like

```
<Select
  key={`dropdown`}
  options={options}
  onChange={onSelect}
  value={defaultValue} />
```

Now it works fine.

So what is the difference `value` and `defaultValue`. Why the `defaultValue` is not able to set the option in react select.

Comment: i imagine the default value with be 'Test value' instead of an object

Comment: Try waiting to render your select element until your options have been fetched from the API. `defaultValue` may only select the option if it exists on the first render.

Comment: @Wex what should i use to wait for select to render like some sort of sleep statement ? sorry for stupid question but have never done anything like that in react.

Comment: Declarative style views are a pretty dramatic shift from their traditional imperative counterpart. Your application state drives the view, which should make your code more predictable and easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delay rendering your `<Select>` element until your API has returned the `options` data. Here's one approach that may work for you:

```
/* options is null/undefined until API sets value to an array */
renderSelect(options) {
  if (options == null) return null;

  return <Select
    key={`dropdown`}
    options={options}
    onChange={onSelect}
    value={defaultValue} />
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.